# What is this perennial plant which survives in the Sonoran Desert naturally?

Tags: identification, flowers, perennials, desert

Plants native to the [Sonoran Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoran%20Desert) require watering every 6 months. The following perennial plant, which I am not sure is native to the Sonoran Desert, was found to thrive in the [Sonoran Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoran%20Desert) solely off rain. What is this plant?

(not flowering yet)
[image: Shub #2]

Comment: @pnuts That seems to have a different coloration. The plant in my picture has a change in color (greenish brown → darker brown) where the branches bifurcate.

Comment: It's a very young plant (<2 years old). Perhaps the desert climate stressed/discolored it?

Comment: @pnuts Yeah, this one is more knobby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be Mexican Petunia ([*Ruellia simplex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruellia_simplex)). Should eventually have small, blue/purple petunia-like trumpet shaped flowers. The plant I have pictured has not been grown in desert climates.

[image]